# Water on touchpad, having issue the next day

Tags: laptop, touchpad

The touchpad pretty much has little or no response to movement in any direction. There was some condensation that got on it from taking it out of a chilled (lots of air-conditioning) room to outside (upper 80's). Before, moisture would cause this and then the problem would resolve itself. However now, it seems that it is not recovering at all.

Some notes: I used tissues, which have oil in them, to attempt to dry it off. Perhaps that oil transferred to the touchpad? I doubt that would be an issue since fingers have lots of oil on them that get on touch screens/touchpads all the  time...

Touchpad details: Acer Aspire Timeline M5. The touchpad is not a solid piece of plastic, and appears to much more sensitive to any water coming into contact with it.

Update: Whew, it works 100% fine now after shutting down and also using one of those USB cooling fans to provide some drying air for it.

Answer (score 1):

You say little, but not none.  I would said a circuit-failure (in the circuit-board sense I mean... there's still a 'circuit' involved between the finger and registering touch) is less likely.  Is this a unibody touchpad?  If there's an edge, I'd take a paper and see if you can slide around the inside edges.

If this isn't under warranty and if you're game, take it apart and clean it up.  Otherwise, take it in.

Answer (score 0):

If the water touched the inside while it was on, then it is dangerous.. it may causes a circuit failure. When something like this happens, you must turn everything off, be sure to dry it all .. even wait a few hours or even a day, and then work normally. The water on devices causes failures when these are on because of the water conductivity ..